# jQuery slide div from left to right on hover of img /text

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to slide text on `hover` of an `img/text`, the other div should also slide along with the `div`.

I have achieved the sliding effect but not able to slide the `div`s along the path.
Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/snehapatani/mqzuD/).

Comment: What do you mean by the expression **sliding `div` along the path**?

Comment: The other divs should also slide along the div in the direction of slide.

Comment: By sliding, if you're referring to letter-by-letter slide, then you need another library.

Comment: I din mean letter by letter, I want to have a smooth transition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.holdingbox').hover(function(){
        $('.rightbox').animate({width: '90px'}, 1000)
    }, function(){
        $('.rightbox').animate({width: '0'}, 1000)
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="holdingbox">
 <span class="leftbox">Stuff</span>
 <span class="rightbox">
     <span class="content">Stuff to reveal</span>
 </span>
</div>
<div class = "box">Text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rightbox {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:0;
    height:30px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.content{
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/mqzuD/10/

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div.holdingbox').bind("mouseenter", function() {
      $(this).find('span').animate({
             "left": "+=5px",
                "opacity" : "show"
              }, {
            duration: 1000
      });   
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mqzuD/8/

Hope this is you want.